# How can I change a path of the GAC folder?

Tags: .net, gac

Can the path of GAC be changed?

I am working on a project where i need to identify all the static information regarding .net framework. I just want to make sure whether the gac path work as static information or not.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: *said in Heavy Weapons Guy voice* OH THIS IS BAD! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heORiZ8l484

Comment: hi i dont want to do this. actually i am working on a project where i need to identify all the static information regarding .net framework, just want to make sure whether the gac path work as static information or not. even i know rellocating gac is bad but still i need to make sure whether its possible or not. dont vote down to reduce the reputation. i think it is very important for me. i dont have ny wrong intention after all.

Comment: Ah, ok. No, as you can see below: It's in the registry.

Comment: I still do not understand your question as to why you want to do this.

Comment: see i told the i just want to confrom whether the gac path can be changed or not. so if i know the .net framework version then i can be sure that this is the gac folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's unlikely that the path will ever change (by someone other than Microsoft). Although .NET4 assemblies are GAC:ed in a new folder.

**Update**

Here is a sample tool using fusion: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/undocumentedfusion.aspx

Comment: yaa i am familiar with that. so i thing i should consider it as a static attribute that cant be change by user only and only microsoft can do so??? isnt it???

Comment: Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557141/how-can-i-get-the-location-of-the-gac-using-c

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea at all. But anyway: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/demystifygac.aspx has a section the describes how to relocate the GAC. The document is a bit outdated, so not shure if it still works.

Answer (score 1):

The GAC folder is in fact a part of Windows OS and you must not change the path to it (if you are not evil-doer)